# JSON Modification on Event change

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have JSON were we are using in html file

```
const LST_HRS_OPEARATION_INPUTS = [
    { id: 1 , openTime: '', closeTime: '',boolIsRequiredInput: true ,boolIsDisabled: false, boolIsRequiredLabel : 'required' ,boolIsRequiredSymbol : 'Required', requiredTextClass:'requiredText', boolShowLabel: true},
    { id: 2 , openTime: '', closeTime: '' ,boolIsRequiredInput: false ,boolIsDisabled :false, boolIsRequiredLabel : '' ,boolIsRequiredSymbol : '  ', requiredTextClass:'requiredText hidden', boolShowLabel: false},
    { id: 3 , openTime: '', closeTime: '' ,boolIsRequiredInput: false, boolIsDisabled:false,boolIsRequiredLabel : '' ,boolIsRequiredSymbol : ' ', requiredTextClass:'requiredText hidden', boolShowLabel: false},
];
```

[image: ```]
Onchange i need to modify the JSON and rendered

```
    handleStartTimeChange(event) {
            console.log('JSON Values', this.lstHoursOfOperation);
            let strOpenTime = event.currentTarget.value;
            console.log('strOpenTime', strOpenTime);
           
            let tempLstHoursOfOperation = this.lstHoursOfOperation.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
                console.log('currentValue ', currentValue.id);
                if (currentValue.openTime != '') {
                    console.log('AfterthecurrentValue ', currentValue.id);
                    currentValue.boolIsDisabled = true;
                    return this.lstHoursOfOperation = currentValue;
                    console.log('After reduce ', this.lstHoursOfOperation);
                }    
            },1);
```

Example on page load first the two rows will be readonly upon entering the value i need disable the readonly tag from JSON and render it back

we got a requirement like on the page load the first two column should be enabled and when the first row second column is filled we need to open the enable the second row , can you suggest which approach i need to take

HTML Template looks like this for the above image

```
<div class="slds-col slds-p-vertical_x-small slds-size_4-of-12">
    <template if:true={session.boolShowLabel}>
        <p class="formLabel slds-p-bottom_small center">Start Time(s)</p>
    </template>
    <lightning-input type="time" class="timeInputFeld" placeholder="HH:MM AM/PM"
        data-id={index} value={session.openTime} variant="label-hidden" key={session.Id}
        required={session.boolIsRequiredInput} disabled={session.boolIsDisabled}  onchange={handleStartTimeChange}>
    </lightning-input>
</div>


<div class="slds-col slds-p-vertical_x-small slds-size_4-of-12">
        <template if:true={session.boolShowLabel}>
            <p class="formLabel slds-p-bottom_small center">End Time(s)</p>
        </template>
        <lightning-input type="time" class="timeInputFeld" placeholder="HH:MM AM/PM"
            data-id={index} data-type="closeTime" value={session.closeTime} variant="label-hidden" key={session.Id}
            required={session.boolIsRequiredInput} disabled={session.boolIsDisabled}  onchange={handleCloseTimeChange}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, could you explain where you are stuck? what is not working?

Comment: I am trying to loop JSON object and i want to keep first input enabled when page is loaded, but disable the other two input , upon on clicking i need to enable the next input item

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using an accumulator, you need to make sure that you are returning a number from all possible outcomes inside your callback function.

- Here you are possibly returning back a value inside the `if` statement (but I'd probably wrap the assignment in brackets - the result of that assignment could actually be returning `true` not a value.

```
if (currentValue.openTime != '') {
  currentValue.boolIsDisabled = true;
  return this.lstHoursOfOperation = currentValue;
}
```

- In the above code, you are not checking for `null` or `undefined`. You should be.
- The current value could be immutable - in that case, you will need to create a new current value object if you want to change attributes of it.
- Put brackets around the assignation - or assign separately.

```
this.lstHoursOfOperation = currentValue;
return this.lstHoursOfOperation;
```

- Finally, you need to return a number at all times (because you are in an accumulator).
- There is no `else` statement, so the function will return `null` or `undefined` if the `if` statement evaluates to false. Then you will try to add the result of that to a number and hey presto `NaN` is going to be the result.

Hope that helps.